# Vagrant box not seen/detected when doing vagrant up

Tags: windows, vagrant

I came across this obscure thing today, so I thought I'd post the solution here for posterity :)

Under Windows, when you create a vagrant box in normal command line / Powershell, the box works just fine and all changes persist.

However, sometimes when you do **vagrant up**, it behaves as if your box never existed, even though you can clearly see the `.vagrant/machines/default/` structure in the directory of the Vagrantfile, and it exists in eg. `C:\Users\<yourname>\VirtualBox VMs\`

Basically you will get an "empty" box.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are basically running it as a different user. Since the boxes are stored in **user-specific** directories in Windows, it is basically exactly that - the box does not exist for the current user.

This happens when try to do `vagrant up` in an elevated command line (Run as administrator). You are not running it as yourself anymore, but as admin. And unless the Admin account has its own virtualbox in `C:\Users\<admin>\VirtualBox VMs\`, it will be empty. It will be an unrelated box, even with the exact same Vagrantfile used for `vagrant up`.

But that is not all, there is a big thing you need to be **REALLY** careful with:

If you do `vagrant up` in the elevated console, after originally creating it as a normal user, the **original box config will disappear!**, meaning if you do `vagrant up` again as a normal user in the normal console, you will not see any of your customizations in the box anymore. However, the good news is that it will not be permanently gone, but you need to do some manual steps to fix it back to normal:

1. In the console, `cd C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\`
2. Then run: `VBoxManage.exe list vms`
3. The output is something like:

   `"ubuntu1604_default_1508830573432_14276" {4a7e6cf3-c611-42b4-a5c2-5760314f7169}
   "ubuntu1604_default_1509090573432_27275" {abcdef23-c613-62b4-55c2-aa60314f7169}`
4. You need to find out which of these is the first one. I'm not 100 % sure, but I think the first one will have a smaller value in the first part after `default`, so in the above case the first row is the original (`150883 < 150909`)
5. Copy the UUID at the end of the original one (`4a7e6cf3-c611-42b4-a5c2-5760314f7169`).
6. Then modify the file in `C:\Path\To\Project\.vagrant\machines\virtualbox\default\id`
7. Change the contents of the file from whatever exists (it is most likely the UUID of the *second* row) to the UUID in step 5.
8. Save the file
9. Now, do `vagrant up` in a normal console. It should boot again into your original box and all your configs and settings should still exist.

Hope this helps!